# What is the SOQL syntax for this join

Tags: soql, account, record-type

What should be the syntax for this type of join?

I need to:

```
SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeId FROM Account
```

and:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType
```

I need to join them on `Account.RecordTypeId` and `RecordType.Id`.

Comment: In addition to cropredy's answer, check the [Trailhead on SOQL](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_soql).

Comment: Thank you  -- I did check this trailhead before writing the post. I wasn't able to figure out the right syntax after checking a trailhead

Comment: and thank you so much for the answer, cropredy, it worked!!

Answer (score 4):

```
select Id, Name, RecordType.Name from Account
```

consult the [SOQL guide on Relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm?search_text=relationship)

Comment: Specifically, it is a **[`Right Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Inner_Join)**.

Comment: In fact, its is amazing how helpful everybody is. Very grateful

Comment: @jane - convention is to mark answers as 'answered' if you got what you needed; helps others in community.